# A First Course in Mathematical Analysis, Ch 1, 1.6 Exercises, Section 1.3, ex 2

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that

\begin{align*}
(a^{2}+b^{2})(c^{2}+d^{2}) & \ge(ac+ad)^{2}\\
a^{2}c^{2}+a^{2}d^{2}+b^{2}c^{2}+b^{2}d^{2} & \ge a^{2}c^{2}+2a^{2}cd+a^{2}d^{2}\\
b^{2}c^{2}+b^{2}d^{2} & \ge 2a^{2}cd\\
b^{2}c^{2}-2a^{2}cd+b^{2}d^{2} & \ge 0\\
b^{2}(c^{2}+d^{2})-2a^{2}cd & \ge 0\\
\end{align*}

Any hints on things to try? It seems trickier than say

$$
(a+b)^{2}(c+d)^{2}\ge(ac+bd)^{2}
$$

Proof (direct):

\begin{align*}
a^{2}c^{2}+a^{2}d^{2}+b^{2}c^{2}+b^{2}d^{2} & \ge a^{2}c^{2}+2abcd+b^{2}d^{2}\\
a^{2}d^{2}+b^{2}c^{2} & \ge2abcd\\
a^{2}d^{2}-2abcd+b^{2}c^{2} & \ge0\\
a^{2}d^{2}-2(ad)(bc)+b^{2}c^{2} & \ge0\\
(ad-bc)^{2} & \ge0
\end{align*}

Comment: Is there a typo in your first inequality?  Should that refer to $(ac+\color{red}b d)^2$?

Comment: It is what the book has. It may be a typo there. I was wondering if it is an errata in the book. The list of errata for David Alexander Brannan's book doesn't include it  though, but perhaps it is one they missed.

Comment: As written, that one is false.  Let $b=0$.

Comment: Robert, if you want to write up an answer saying the same I'll accept it. Thanks for the counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the inequality is false.

$$(ac+ad)^2=a(c+d)^2=a^2c^2+2a^2cd+a^2d^2.$$

If $b=0 \text{ but } acd \neq 0 \text{ with } cd \gt 0$, then

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = a^2(c^2+d^2) = a^2c^2+a^2d^2 \lt a^2c^2+2a^2cd+a^2d^2.$$

As noted in the comments, I suspect the right-hand side is supposed to be $(ac+\color{red} b d)^2.$